# JsonPropertyAttribute not working with . in name

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json-deserialization

I'm creating an Azure DevOps webhook endpoint for a work item creation trigger using ASP.NET Core 3.1. The payload produced by DevOps has . characters in some property names on the Fields array

```
"System.AreaPath": "FabrikamCloud",
"System.TeamProject": "FabrikamCloud",
"System.IterationPath": "FabrikamCloud\\Release 1\\Sprint 1",
"System.WorkItemType": "Bug",
"System.State": "New",
"System.Reason": "New defect reported",
"System.CreatedDate": "2014-07-15T17:42:44.663Z",
"System.CreatedBy": {
```

I've created models to represent the various levels of the object graph and the parents are serialising nicely but even if I annotate these properties appropriately they don't de-serialise and all values are set to defaults

```
public class Fields
{
    [JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")]
    public string SystemAreaPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.TeamProject")]
    public string SystemTeamProject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.IterationPath")]
    public string SystemIterationPath { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.WorkItemType")]
    public string SystemWorkItemType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.State")]
    public string SystemState { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.Reason")]
    public string SystemReason { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.CreatedDate")]
    public DateTime SystemCreatedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.CreatedBy")]
    public UserDetails SystemCreatedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.ChangedDate")]
    public DateTime SystemChangedDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.ChangedBy")]
    public UserDetails SystemChangedBy { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("System.Title")]
    public string SystemTitle { get; set; }
```

Anyone know how to deal with property names containing the decimal point?

Comment: What are you using `Newtonsoft.Json` or `System.Text.Json`? Show us how you deserealize

Comment: I de-serialise implicitly `[HttpPost] public IActionResult Create(Fields fields)`

Comment: We haven't specified newtonsoft anyway, but I don't even see how you get away from having it. Our project was setup with Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Json (2.2.0), which has the JsonPatch lib which has Newtonsoft.Json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
[JsonPropertyName("System.AreaPath")]
```

instead of

```
[JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")]
```

from System.Text.Json, which is used by default in .net core 3 as mentioned by @Hintee

Answer (score 3):

The JsonProperty attribute works just fine as long as you're using Newtonsoft Json to handle JSON serialization/deserialization. But AspNet Core 3+ uses  **System.Text.Json** by default.

Here's an article to configure it to use Newtonsoft:

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/